# How to correctly use Reach Router Links with a Fluent UI Nav

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

Is there a way to make the Fluent UI (formerly Office Fabric UI) Nav component correctly work replacing it's `<a>` element links with a custom link such as `<Link>` from Reach Router?

Fluent UI Nav provides an `onRenderLink` props but that only changes the inner content innermost `<a>` element.  It leaves the outer wrapping element with a traditional `<a>` which causes full page re-renders when the user uses it.

It also provides the `linkAs` prop but that changes the entire content of the "Group Header" and takes a way all of the nice CSS styling advantages of using the `Nav` in the first place.

Is there a way to actually get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I did a little more googling and found this codepen which uses `LinkAs` :

```
(props) => {
   return <Link className={props.className} style={{color: 'inherit', boxSizing: 'border-box'}} to={props.href}>
     <span style={{display: 'flex'}}>
      { !!props.iconProps && <Icon style={{margin: '0 4px'}} {...props.iconProps} /> }
      {props.children}
      </span>

    </Link> ;
  }
```

A little bit disappointing that you basically have to reverse engineer their CSS and render it yourself in order to get this working.

Comment: Tried this but the Nav itself doesn't update to reflect the location after clicking the link. Is there more to this (like also setting `selectedKey`)?

Comment: I found the original of this here (https://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/EOVXGQ) but it doesn't even work properly in Codepen. This Nav control seems to be buggy at best and possibly worthless.

Comment: I added `@withRouter` to my parent component of the Nav and the Nav started following the route. It wasn't re-rendering before on route changes.